# How can I programatically control the visibility of each point in areaspline c3 charts?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Programmatically control visibility (CSS and show / hide) of each point in C3 charts type Area Spline.
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syed_raza_khalid/g2jjcw40/19/) example.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200]
    ],
    type: 'area-spline'
  },
  point: {
    show: true
  }
});
```

[image: image of C3js chart]

Answer (score 0):

Points in the C3 configuration only allows for all or none, but afterwards the visibility of the points can be altered through selection of the circles via the c3 css classes. These circles are bound to the data points so then writing a function that picks out the data points you want can be used to control visibility as below:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['pete', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['steve', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    },
    point: {
        show: true
    }
});

var visx = d3.set([2,4]);
d3.selectAll(".c3-chart-line .c3-circles").selectAll(".c3-circle").style("display", function(d) {
    //return visx.has(d.x) ? null : "none";  // show points at x values 2 and 4
    return d.value > 150 ? null : "none";  // or show points when value is above 150
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ud8gyphw/

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the effort and explanation but i was asking is it possible to do through c3 configuration instead of writing code through d3.

Comment: "is it possible to do through c3 configuration" - no :-)

Comment: This answer should have an up vote, there is so much effort put into this answer and it is very helpful. @mgraham thanks for your efforts and the answer, +1.

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer. C3 is not capable of everything that D3 can do. It is just a wrapper to simplify common functions. For advanced functionality, D3 is needed and it can be mixed with C3

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to:

> Is it possible to do through C3 configuration instead of writing code through D3.

Is **yes** this is because C3 is used to generate D3-based charts by wrapping the code required to construct the entire chart meaning we don't have to write D3 code any more.

You should be able to configure C3js without D3js because **we don't have to write D3 code any more**.

NOTE: C3 depends on D3, so please load D3 too.

You can read more about C3js over on the [Official Website](http://c3js.org/).
You can also check out the C3js [Docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html).

Comment: Sorry for my stupid mistake before, It appears I was referencing D3 & C3 from **ONE** file, leading me to think that you do not need D3 as a dependency, once again sorry for my mistake :)